# Pandas count per time (XX:XX:XX) based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

With the following df:

```
Real_time SName VT  on Act_win ratio
11:11:20    x   5   yes zoom    90
11:11:30    x   15  yes chrome  90
11:11:40    x   25  yes zoom    90
11:11:50    x   35  no  zoom    90
11:12:00    x   45  yes zoom    90
11:12:10    x   55  yes zoom    90
11:12:20    x   65  yes zoom    50
11:12:30    x   75  no  zoom    60
11:12:40    x   85  yes chrome  60
11:12:50    x   95  yes zoom    60
11:13:00    x   105 yes zoom    20
11:11:20    y   5   yes zoom    99
11:11:30    y   15  yes zoom    88
11:11:40    y   25  yes chrome  77
11:11:50    y   35  no  chrome  49
11:12:00    y   45  yes zoom    56
11:12:10    y   55  yes zoom    46
11:12:20    y   65  yes zoom    90
11:12:30    y   75  no  zoom    90
11:12:40    y   85  yes zoom    90
11:12:50    y   95  yes zoom    90
11:13:00    y   105 yes chrome  50
```

I need to group by timestamp and act_win and count instances in which `df["act_win"] = "zoom"` per timestamp, where 0 occurrences should be counted as 0 (and not have the row dropped).

In addition, I would like to use "mean" for "ratio" on the same condition.

Lastly, I need to do the same thing with multiple conditions, given `df["act_win"] = "zoom"` and `df["on"] = "yes"`.

I got stuck because I just do a total count and then drop unnecessary rows. However if there where no "zoom" entries in a specific timestamp, it won't work.
Unfortunately the answers I have found so far create a factorial column for months which doesn't help me in this situation.

EDIT -
expected result for final combined criteria (both `df["on"] = "yes"` and `df["act_win"] = "zoom"`):

```
Real_time count mean_r
11:11:20    2   94.5
11:11:30    1   88
11:11:40    1   90
11:11:50    0   0
11:12:00    2   73
11:12:10    2   68
11:12:20    2   70
11:12:30    0   0
11:12:40    1   90
11:12:50    2   75
11:13:00    1   20
```

Comment: What is the excepted output ?

Comment: sorry. slipped my mind.. added

Comment: This is the comment from Kantushov Herman. It got hiddent when I deleted my answer: > Thanks Balaji. Not exactly. I would like the time to be aggregated and the mean to be done only on the specified criteria - so at 11:11:30 only person y had the combination of both on = 'yes' and act_win = 'zoom'. His ratio is 88, so the answer is 88 (the mean for the specific time) . I added an expected result. sorry if I wasn't clear

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way to do this, but it is calculated by grouping the results against the conditional extraction results. Then I create a data frame from it with a unique timestamp and combine it with

```
df1 = df[(df['Act_win'] == 'zoom')&(df['on'] == 'yes')].groupby(['Real_time','Act_win']).agg(count=('ratio','count'), mean_r=('ratio','mean'))
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Real_time':df['Real_time'].unique().tolist()})
df2 = df2.merge(df1, on='Real_time', how='outer')
df2['Act_win'] = df2['Act_win'].fillna(method='ffill')
df2.fillna(0, inplace=True)

df2
    Real_time   Act_win count   mean_r
0   11:11:20    zoom    2.0 94.5
1   11:11:30    zoom    1.0 88.0
2   11:11:40    zoom    1.0 90.0
3   11:11:50    zoom    0.0 0.0
4   11:12:00    zoom    2.0 73.0
5   11:12:10    zoom    2.0 68.0
6   11:12:20    zoom    2.0 70.0
7   11:12:30    zoom    0.0 0.0
8   11:12:40    zoom    1.0 90.0
9   11:12:50    zoom    2.0 75.0
10  11:13:00    zoom    1.0 20.0
```

Comment: that should work. However, if you don't mind for the generic solution, perhaps add bfill after ffill method, or fill with specific value ("zoom" in my case) so if that first value is NA it would work as well.